# Run systemctl in container

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

I want to set up some stuff when starting Kubernetes node worker. Specifically, I change systemd service configuration and apply it (systemctl daemon-reload), but from inside the container, I don't know how to configure systemd of node worker

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you actually want to do, but

1. Usually systemd is not installed inside containers
2. I don't know what you want to implement, but I pretty sure that run systemd daemon inside container is a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51979553/is-it-recommended-to-run-systemd-inside-docker-container)
3. In most cases if you want to start long running background process, that will be better idea to run it in separate container and connect two containers.
4. If you need to do some action on container start before run main process, just override [entrypoint](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#define-a-command-and-arguments-when-you-create-a-pod), and prepend own command before main one (you may add it with [&](https://www.maketecheasier.com/run-bash-commands-background-linux/) symbol to run in background, but it is a not smart solution)

Comment: I run k8s cluster on AWS, with node worker - spot instance. Every day, we will scale the auto-scaling group from N node worker -> 0 node worker in 12 pm for saving resource, thus there will be new servers. Recently, our server (with image instance is specified when creating k8s cluster) run a cronjob from 6 am - 7 am, so my server will reload configuration systemd and restart network service, so my applications running on node worker are disconnected with outside. Therefore I want to turn off this cron job.

Comment: Sorry, still can't figure out actual problem and task details. Also I'm not familiar with AWS k8s